# HttpResponseException in Java Based Adapter

Tags: java, javascript, https, httpresponse, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to do a post request to a URL https://jazz.net/. I am getting the following error.

> invocation of javascript function 'addTwoIntegers' has failed: Unauthorized"
>
> FWLSE0101E: Caused by: org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized

here is my java code :

```
    HttpGet query = new HttpGet(projectAreaURI);
    HttpPost q= new HttpPost(projectAreaURI);
    HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpUtils.setupLazySSLSupport(httpClient);
    q.addHeader("Accept","application/xml");
    
    q.addHeader("Accept-Encoding","gzip");
    q.addHeader("User-Agent","yes");
    q.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    String postMessage="offlineData={'projectAreaItemId':'_iTuLUmxfEeKR3t32SVbLKQ','executables':[{'terItemId':'_TNoyQW6qEeKR3t32SVbLKQ','scriptItemId':'_DF89AW6qEeKR3t32SVbLKQ'}]}";
    q.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(
            postMessage.toString().getBytes("UTF8")));
    
    query.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    
    
    // Access to the Service Descriptor document
    HttpResponse response = HttpUtils.sendPostForSecureDocument(projectAreaURI, q, "ashwinimaddala", "ash_1646",httpClient);
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        response.getEntity().consumeContent();
        throw new     HttpResponseException(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(), response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase());
    }
    return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"";
```

sendPostForSecureDocument():

```
    if (DEBUG)
        System.out.println(">> PUT(1) " + put.getURI());
    HttpResponse documentResponse = httpClient.execute(put);
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println(">> Response Headers:");
        HttpUtils.printResponseHeaders(documentResponse);
    }
    System.out.println(documentResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    if (documentResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
        System.out.println(put.getURI());

        Header header = documentResponse.getFirstHeader(AUTHREQUIRED);
        if ((header != null) && ("authrequired".equals(header.getValue()))) {
            documentResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
            HttpPost formPost = new HttpPost(serverURI
                    + "/j_security_check");
            List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_username", login));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("j_password", password));
            formPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
if (DEBUG)
                System.out.println(">> POST " + formPost.getURI());
            HttpResponse formResponse = httpClient.execute(formPost);
            if (DEBUG)
                HttpUtils.printResponseHeaders(formResponse);

            header = formResponse.getFirstHeader(AUTHREQUIRED);
            if ((header != null)
                    && ("authfailed".equals(header.getValue()))) {
                throw new InvalidCredentialsException(
                        "Authentication failed");
            } else {
                formResponse.getEntity().consumeContent();
                if (DEBUG)
                    System.out.println(">> PUT(2) " + put.getURI());
                try {
                    HttpPut put2 = (HttpPut) put.clone();
                    return httpClient.execute(put2);
                } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return documentResponse;
```

Comment: Please check the server logs for the exception and post the stack trace.

Comment: i cant find the server logs here.. its a java adapter i am writing in the worklight project ..

Comment: Where is the function "addTwoIntegers"? Are you basing your entire project on a sample app.....?

Answer (score 0):

Re-visiting this question, it seems to me it could be the same issue reported here: [org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056361/org-apache-http-conn-httphostconnectexception-connection-to-https-jazz-net-re)

Basically, jazz.net requires using port 443. So in your Java code, just like in a Worklight adapter, make sure you use port 443...