# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have upgraded my worklight with 5.0.5 to 5.0.6 .when i have worked on 5.0.5 it worked fine but the same code when i am using in updated version worklight 5.0.6 it gives me this error

response [/apps/services/api/RTMLight/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"responseID":"2","errors":["Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/

worklight.js (line 1112)

Procedure invocation error. Runtime: Http request failed: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://jazz.net refused

Comment: Add your adapter's XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not sound related to any upgrade issue between 5.0.5 to 5.0.6. From the error message this seems more related to connectivity issues.

Make sure that your adapter's connectionPolicy uses the port child-element with value 443, like this:

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>https</protocol>
        <domain>jazz.net</domain>
        <port>443</port>
</connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
</connectivity>
```